# Yosemite Kernel panics involving com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

I have experienced 5 kernel panics over the last few months. Using a mid-2012 MacBook Pro running Yosemite 10.10.4.

I have reinstalled Yosemite and have erased, repartitioned and reinstalled. I have been on the phone to AppleCare and have had a Genius run diagnostic tests, nothing found. No one has yet looked at the logs.

The only thing I can find in the logs that is common to every kernel panic is that the last loaded and/or unloaded kext in every case has been:

com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.2.2b5

or

com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC   4.3.3b1

Does anyone have any ideas as to what the problem might be?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess: the kernel panics appeared with the 10.10.3 update? Well, then I am 98% certain it is a bug in OS X Yosemite. Welcome [aboard](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7000724). The kernel panics are totally erratic, some users have also graphics glitches. The only common feature is having a Intel HD 4000 GPU.

On MacBook Pros with dual GPU you can avoid the problem by **disabling Automatic Graphics Switching** (System Preferences > Energy Saver).

After countless phone calls with Apple, I will take my Mac to the Apple Store tomorrow. I am sure they won't find a thing. Then they will keep my Mac for five days, replace the logic board and the issue will persist. Please proof me wrong Apple...

Please contribute to the [thread in the apple discussion forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7000724) and file a bug report (with link to the thread).

Comment: Correct. In fact the issue first appeared for me right at the end of the 10.10.3 installation process. I also have the Intel HD 4000 GPU. So 10.10.4 hasn't fixed it?

Comment: No :( Apparently the beta of 10.11 does. Please contribute to the Apple discussions forum and file a bug report.

Comment: almost forgot. On MBPs you can disable graphics switching. I did not have kernel panics since then. Your case is interesting since you have a consistent process popping up in the log. Most people have no log or a different process every time.

Comment: I do not have that option as my Mac only has one GPU.

Comment: Update: Because of the consistent mention of USBCDC, Apple phone support thought my issue might be caused by a USB peripheral. I have a USB hub (a very inexpensive one) and two hard drives connected most of the time. I plan to disconnect the peripherals one at a time and then test. Hope to keep the thread updated - see you in 53 days!